# How to get error response of a post Request using Python aiohttp package

Tags: python, rest, aiohttp

I am using aiohttp and could not able to get the body of the response from the servers, anyone can advise me on how to handle this.

below is the sample code.

```
async with session.post(url, data=data, auth=auth, headers=headers) as resp:
    return resp

form the above i need to get the error message for a particular fild,

for ex:{'username':'some username',email:"stackoverflow",password:"12345"}
```

The above example email format is wrong. the expectation of the response body should be as below(this is the postman response body).

```
{
  "code": "2004",
  "reason": "Email format is wrong",
  "errorType": "BusinessLogicError",
  "errorDetails": null
}
```